# How can I set connection timeout for OkHttpClient? 2017

Tags: android, okhttp, connection-timeout

It is easy to say it's duplicate but it isn't.

I read many post about how to set the connection timeout in `android` but the post are 4-7 years old and I think that we all need an update about this topic because those methods are deprecated or no longer exist.

So the question is how can I set my connection timeout when I am waiting for a response from the server?

```
final Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();

if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                          //success
} else {
       //unsuccessful
}
```

Comment: If you are using the HttpClient API in the Android SDK, **stop**. That has been deprecated and removed. Use something else (e.g., OkHttp). If you are using the standalone Apache HttpClient library for Android, you need to specify which version, as that API has shifted over the years.

Comment: my bad. I wanted to write okhttp . I am using 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'

Comment: Um, your question is all about HttpClient, though. If you are actually using OkHttp instead, [here is how you configure timeouts](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#timeouts).

Comment: Can you please post the answer as response so I can vote it? Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create your `OkHttpClient` through an `OkHttpClient.Builder`, [there are `connectTimeout()`, `readTimeout()`, and `writeTimeout()` methods](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#timeouts) that you can call for the various timeout options.

If you need to override them for a specific HTTP request, call `newBuilder()` on your `OkHttpClient`. That gives you an `OkHttpClient.Builder` with the same settings as you used originally. [You can override those as needed](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes#per-call-configuration), and create a temporary `OkHttpClient` from the new `Builder`, using that for this one-off call.

Comment: Thank you for your response!!